# How do I template a function that takes templated args and applies a templated function on them in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, alias, pointer-to-member

I have a bunch of static class functions that take in varying number of {string, int, float} params and an Output param. There may be different behavior for the same parameters based on the function called. For example:

```
static void ChangeOutput1(const string& foo, int bar, Output* output);
static void ChangeOutput2(int bar, Output* output);
static void ChangeOutput3(float foo, Output* output);
static void ChangeOutput4(float foo, Output* output);  // behaves differently from ChangeOutput3
```

I'd like to have a simple, safe way of writing templates to perform a similar behavior over each of the functions, basically calling with an Output argument and converting it to a string to return. Ideally without having to specify the parameter types again. It might look something like this:

```
template<typename... Args, int (*ChangeOutputFn)(Args...)>
string OutputString(Args... args) {
    Output output;
    ChangeOutputFn(args..., &output);
    return ConvertToString(output);
}

// Is there a way to alias static templated functions?
using StringOutput1 = OutputString<ChangeOutput1>;
using StringOutput2 = OutputString<ChangeOutput2>;
using StringOutput3 = OutputString<ChangeOutput3>;
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this. I'm both unsure of how to write OutputString and how I would alias or define the static functions. There are less elegant solutions, but they require repetitive boilerplate that I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Just give them all the same name (i.e. overload, don't template).

Comment: Für C++11, have a look at variadic templates. However, I didn't check if it can perfectly satisfy all your requirements

Comment: @n.m. - I can't name them all the same thing; the same signature might have different semantics for different cases (e.g. there are multiple cases that just take a single int, but do different things to Output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a class, you may do something like:

```
template <typename T, T f> struct OutputString;

template<typename... Args, void (*ChangeOutputFn)(Args...)>
struct OutputString<void (*)(Args...), ChangeOutputFn>
{
    template <typename ... Ts>
    auto operator()(Ts... args)
    -> decltype(ChangeOutputFn(std::forward<Ts>(args)..., std::declval<Output *>()),
                std::string{})
    {
        Output output;
        ChangeOutputFn(std::forward<Ts>(args)..., &output);
        return ConvertToString(output);
    }
};
```

And then

```
using StringOutput1 = OutputString<decltype(&ChangeOutput1), &ChangeOutput1>;
using StringOutput2 = OutputString<decltype(&ChangeOutput2), &ChangeOutput2>;
using StringOutput3 = OutputString<decltype(&ChangeOutput3), &ChangeOutput3>;
```

and use it as

```
std::string s2 = StringOutput2{}(42);
std::string s3 = StringOutput3{}(4.2f);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c03285027bf555a)

Comment: crazy template magic, but presumably the problem was unnecessarily complicated to begin with. Why not simply overload the same function, similar to `std::to_string()`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Compiling this code with c++11 gives me the error "'int(int, struct Output*)' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
 using StringOutput1 = OutputString<decltype(ChangeOutput1), ChangeOutput1>;" Something I'm missing?

Comment: @Walter it cannot be overloaded since the ChangeOutput3 and ChangeOutput4 have the very same signature

Comment: @Jarod42 ok found out. decltype does not perform pointer to function decay, so the "using" lines must be decltype(&ChangeOutput1)...

Comment: @LoPiTaL: Demo added, and compilation fixed.

Comment: I really appreciate the help; is there any way where you don't need to initialize the struct?

Comment: @rhi: If you dislike `StringOutput2{}(args)` syntax, you may change `operator()` by a static named method to have something like `StringOutput2::f(args)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you move the Output argument to the front.

```
static void ChangeOutput1(Output*, const std::string& foo, int bar);
static void ChangeOutput2(Output*, int bar);
static void ChangeOutput3(Output*, float foo);
static void ChangeOutput4(Output*, float foo);
```

Now you can have this template:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::function<std::string(Args...)>
mkOutput (void (*ChangeOutputFn)(Output*, Args...))
{
    return [ChangeOutputFn](Args... args)->std::string{
        Output output;
        ChangeOutputFn(&output, args...);
        return ConvertToString(output);
    };
}
```

and "function aliases" look like this:

```
auto a1 = mkOutput(ChangeOutput1);
auto a2 = mkOutput(ChangeOutput2);
auto a3 = mkOutput(ChangeOutput3);
auto a4 = mkOutput(ChangeOutput4);
```

Note 1. You **cannot** have this syntax

```
OutputString<ChangeOutput1>
```

because `ChangeOutput1` is a value and `OutputString` must either know its type beforehand or receive it as another template argument.

It is possible to have something like this

```
OutputString<decltype(ChangeOutput1), ChangeOutput1>
```

and then eliminate the repetition with a macro, but that's just ugly.

I choose to pass the function at run time rather than at compile time, it's easier this way.